# Can't set Detail label of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to create a screen with `UITableview` that consists of sections and different row types ([shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbPAw.png)). Problem is, when trying to change the value of Detail label in Frequency cell, it says it's a get-only property. Frequency cell is set to type "Right Detail" in storyboard.

My code is:

```
    let frequencyCellID = "frequencyCell"
    let decksCellID = "decksCell"
    let pickerCellID = "pickerCell"
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell?

    switch (indexPath.section,indexPath.row){
    case (0,0): cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(frequencyCellID)
        //line below shows error
        cell?.detailTextLabel? = "test"
    case (0,1): cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(pickerCellID)
    case (1,0): cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(decksCellID)
        cell?.detailTextLabel? = "test"
    default: break
    }
    return cell!
```

Also, how can I avoid force unwrapping the cell in last line? I tried to initialize an empty TableViewCell but there seems to be no empty initializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should request a cell from a table view like this:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(frequencyCellID, forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

There's additional `indexPath` parameter, and this method guarantees to return a non-optional UITableViewCell instance. This will also make your cell instance non-optional, thus you won't have to unwrap it. You should read about the differences of those two methods, there's a lot of info about that.

Another problem you have: detailTextLabel is a UILabel instance, so you need to set its content through `text` property. Like this:

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "test"
```

Comment: All right, I see my mistake in the text label problem. But what do you suggest to put in the indexpath argument inside the switch?

Comment: just pass the indexPath that you received as an argument in `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`. You can replace the line in your first switch case with this: `cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(frequencyCellID, forIndexPath: indexPath)` and it will compile and run.

Comment: Okay, thanks :) 
While we're at it, I'd like to update the detail label based on the picker view (which has its own class). Should I create a global variable in either `UITableView` or in `UIPickerView` that is changed in `pickerView:didSelectRow`?

Comment: In `pickerView:didSelectRow` you do `let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "updated text"
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot :) One more thing, there is no method `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier`, only `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, at least in Swift 2.2. For future readers' sake I'd suggest you edit your answer :)

Comment: Oh, thanks for noticing it, looks like I'm nothing without auto-complete :)

Answer (score 0):

In the line with an error, you are assigning a `String` to `cell?.detailTextLabel?` which is an instance of `UILabel?` and not a `String`.  To assign a `String` to the label's text, do `cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "test"`.

Also, the `detailTextLabel?` property is `readonly`, which means you unfortunately cannot assign your own `UILabel?` instance to it.  What you can do, though, is set whatever properties on it you need in order to customize it to your liking.  So you can do `cell?.detailTextLabel?.backgroundColor =` or `cell?.detailTextLabel?.font =`, etc.

As for unwrapping the cell, you should get your cell with

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(frequencyCellID, forIndexPath:indexPath)
```

This method doesn't return an optional.

Comment: Unfortunately `cellForRowAtIndexPath` doesn't return an optional.

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` doesn't return an optional and returning nil will be reported as a compile time error.